# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'HashTableV2'

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, machine-learning

When I train a model with Tensorflow 1.4.1, I use feature column like this:

```
school_col = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
        "school", [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=tf.int64)
```

Then I want to use C++ to load the model and do inference, so I try to build libtensorflow-core.a by running tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_linux.sh on MacOS. I've appended

```
tensorflow/core/kernels/lookup_table_op.cc
tensorflow/core/kernels/initializable_lookup_table.cc
tensorflow/core/kernels/lookup_table_init_op.cc
tensorflow/core/kernels/lookup_util.cc
tensorflow/core/ops/lookup_ops.cc
```

to the tensorflow/contrib/makefile/tf_op_files.txt.

However, when I run the C++ program on CentOS 7, TF raised an error:

> No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'HashTableV2' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
>
> [[Node: input_layer_1/school_indicator/school_lookup/hash_table = HashTableV2container="", key_dtype=DT_INT64, shared_name="", use_node_name_sharing=false, value_dtype=DT_INT64]]

How can I solve this problem?